# override environment variables

Tags: linux, command-line, environment-variables, rm

I would like to override a particular environment variable on a one-shot basis.  The system currently has a variable for the "rm" command, forcing verification for each file.  In general I am fine with this; it's saved me on a number of occasions.

However, it gets in the way sometimes.  I have a large number of diagnostics files that are constantly generated and I periodically delete them.  However, it takes forever to respond to the "rm: remove regular file `../logs/abort20150303013725_diag.txt'?" for every one of hundreds of files.

In this case I **know** I want to delete all of the files.  There has to be a way to say "ignore the environment variables and issue the command exactly how I enter it".  Basically behave as if there was no environment variable for rm for that particular invokation.  While keeping the "confirm all" operation unless explicitly overridden.

Comment: How exactly is the behaviour of `rm` changed? Is there an alias? A function? A script? What variables are you talking about?

Comment: `type rm` will show it is probably an alias. Use `/bin/rm` for example, or remove the alias with `unalias rm`.

Answer (score 0):

most likely `rm` is an alias to `rm -i`.

1. `unalias rm` (this will last for the current session)
2. use `\rm` file (which use plain rm )
3. `/bin/rm`

Comment: 3 appears to be the solution.  It's a one-shot, which is exactly what I want.  And it requires no changes to anything other than adding a few characters to the command.

Answer (score 0):

First locate the command `rm` by typing `which rm`. An example of the output is:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
        /bin/rm
```

Then use the full command path for a one-shot solution. Based on the above output, you might type:

```
/bin/rm <your file to be removed>
```